# php mail form code not working

Tags: php, validation, email

I have a basic email form that I can not get to work, it's been taken from a tutorial online and for some reason I can not get this to send an email to the email address.
The email form registers that all the fields are correctly fields out and displays the sent text but the email never seems to come through:

```
   <?php
 function spamcheck($field)
  {

  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);


  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
   else
    {
    return FALSE;
     }
  }
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))

  {
   $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['email']);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {
    echo "Invalid input";
    }
  else{

  $fullname = $_REQUEST['fullname'] ;
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $link = $_REQUEST['link'] ;
  mail("myemail@me.co.uk", "Track link from: " .$fullname,
  $link, "From:" . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
    }
  }
else
  {

echo'<div id="formcontainer">
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
<div id="form">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Your name</div><!--end .label -->
    <div class="input">
    <input type="text" id="fullname" class="detail" name="fullname" value="" />
    </div><!--end .input -->
    <div class="context">e.g Derek Datch</div><!-- end .context -->
    </div><!-- end .row -->

    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Your email</div><!--end .label -->
    <div class="input">
    <input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="email" value="" />
    </div><!--end .input -->
    <div class="context">We will not share your email with anyone.</div><!-- end .context -->
    </div><!-- end .row -->

    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Link to track</div><!--end .label -->
    <div class="input">
    <input type="text" id="link" class="detail" name="link" value="" />
    </div><!--end .input -->
    <div class="context">e.g a link from Sound Cloud, Dropbox or any other files sharing website.</div><!-- end .context -->
    </div><!-- end .row -->

    <div id="sumbit">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send link" />
    </div><!-- end #sumbit -->

</div><!-- end #form -->
</form>
</div><!-- end #formcontainer -->';
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? Is your server able to send mails? Do you get any errors/notices with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`?

Comment: Do you have a mail server installed?

Comment: Not worth making as an "answer". Just change your action to `action=""` instead  of `action="contact.php"` and it will work, since your form/handler are inside the same file, so it seems. (TESTED)

Comment: @Fred-ii- maybe the file is named contact.php?

Comment: No, look at the OP's code carefully and you will see that it's not the case. @kingkero

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm dying here not seeing any sign of that but more and more of bad code..

Comment: There's nothing bad really about the OP's code. It's supposed to run internally within itself. My guess the OP got this code from the web, assuming the action should be passed to `contact.php`, which doesn't make sense to start with. Just follow it closely ;-) @kingkero

Comment: I'm not getting a result from changing the action to "". Your write @Fred-ii- I have taken this direct from a tutorial and edited it to my means. I had it working before I started to add the $name in the echo statement that followed, I have since removed this but still not working. I've now even tried adding the email sent to, the subject and the headers as a variable and using them in the mail function. It's still not working. I greatly appreciate your help with this, I don't understand how I had it working and then just broke it, I can't see the part that's doing it.

Comment: Are you running this on a hosted server or your own? @ThePagan

Comment: No, its on one.com. I managed to get it working but then somehow played a little too much with the code, I'm thinking I'll start again and save my progress a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now edited the original question to show working code. Thanks for all your help with this, I'm still not sure what was not working. I have just re written the code and it now seems to work. I must have missed something but just couldn't see it.